# Tag list on the right hand side of Questions does not appear at times

Tags: support, tags

The tag list on the right of the Question happens sometimes, perhaps depending on ip address:

[image]

I haven't checked with any browser other than Firefox (26 and 27).

Comment: It's A/B testing, or something.

Comment: It's been going on for several days now.

Comment: My memory tells me that a question like this was also asked several days ago, and the official response was "A/B testing".

Comment: I found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219767/tags-are-not-showing-up-on-the-right-side-of-the-screen.

Comment: Yeah, that one.